# Do C library functions generally mimic the Intel assembly language style?

Tags: programming-languages, c

I'm looking at the basic strcpy function. It is

```
char *strcpy( char *dest, const char *src );
```

Which reminds me of assembly language: `MOV   DEST, SRC`

Comment: You just need to ask yourself which came first C or Intel *86 chips. Or put it another way processors exist to run programs on, any new processor is going to attempt to efficiently support all features of an existing popular language.

Comment: @James - That's a very good point; Thank You So Much!

Comment: `strcpy(dest, src)` or `dest = src`. No, in C, these don't accomplish the exact same thing, but the general pattern (destination before source) is the same in both. If C had used a syntax like TI-BASIC's `value → variable` (source before destination) for assignment, maybe it would have been `strcpy(src, dest)` too.

Comment: @James Anderson:  The Intel 8008 was released in 1972, and that set the tone for the Intel processors to follow (8080, 8085, 8086 and beyond), and that's about the time C was released.  Looks like independent development to me.

Comment: @David -- but Cs predecessors such as BCPL had already been around for a while. Besides nearly every contemporary instruction set  (PDP-11, IBM 360, Unisys, Burroughs etc.) implemented a block move instruction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Intel processors were not yet invented when the C library was designed, so no.

Your observation that C is similar to assembly language is correct, however.  C was designed to replace assembly when Unix needed to be ported to other architectures than the original PDP-11 and many constructs map directly to the PDP-11 machine language.

I do not know if the machine language of the PDP-11 was similar to Intel (dest, src) or the reason for the API convention was just that it was this way that made most sense to the designer.

See http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix/history_timeline.html for time line.

Comment: Yes, at least with the usual DEC assemblers (e.g., Macro-11), you'd also use `mov dst, src`.